# Spring Data JPA - Massive update does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, and package as an executable JAR with a restful architecture I have this repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MenuPriceAlertNotificationRepository 
                    extends CrudRepository<MenuPriceAlertNotification, Long> {




    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update MenuPriceAlertNotification n set n.read = :status where n.id in :notificationIdList and n.user.id = :userId")
    void changeNotificationListReadStatus(  @Param("notificationIdList") List<Long> notificationIdList, 
                                            @Param("userId") long userId, 
                                            @Param("status") boolean status);


}
```

but does not update the rows in the DB

Comment: Could you define what "massive update" means ?
Does it work if you reduce the number of elements that need to be updated ?

Comment: no, maybe the title os no accurate

Comment: It does return any exception?

Comment: And are you sure that the method finishes with its execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
    @Transactional(propagation =Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE,readOnly=false,transactionManager="transactionManager")
@Query("update MenuPriceAlertNotification n set n.read = :status where n.id in :notificationIdList and n.user.id = :userId")
void changeNotificationListReadStatus(  @Param("notificationIdList") List<Long> notificationIdList, 
                                        @Param("userId") long userId, 
                                        @Param("status") boolean status);
```

if any issue inform.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want to do, but as an update query, you can also use the `save()` function from the `CrudRepository` by selecting the id primary key of the raw you want to update in your table.

An other point is the `List<Long> notificationIdList` parameters that you want to take into account, are you sure that you can give a list to `@Param`? If not, you can use a for loop on the elements of the list and call the query function `changeNotificationListReadStatus()` at each iteration.